# Referencing Javascript variable in OnKeyUp event problem

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

I've declared two variables, COURSE_ID_List and COURSE_ID_timerId. They then get passed as parameters to the SetFilter function from the OnKeyUp event.

If the list is undefined, it should initialise it. The problem is that the list is always undefined, so I assume the COURSE_ID_List used in the OnKeyUp event is being passed in by value and not by reference. How can I get around this?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function SetFilter(ddl, value, list, timerId) {
  if (list == undefined)
    list = new ListFilter(ddl);
  clearTimeout(timerId);
  timerId = setTimeout(function() { list.SetFilter(value);}, 1500);
}

var COURSE_ID_List;
var COURSE_ID_List_timerId;

</script>

<input name="Course" type="text" id="COURSE_ID" onKeyUp="SetFilter('COURSE_ID', this.value, COURSE_ID_List, COURSE_ID_List_timerId);" />
```

Comment: Note that the *keyup* event isn't a great way of detecting user input.  There are other events you can use that catch other kinds of input like pasting or dragging and dropping.  See http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be the answer you are looking for.

```
(function() {
    var COURSE_ID_List = {},
    COURSE_ID_List_timerId = {};
    window.setFilter=function(ddl, value) {
        var list = COURSE_ID_List[ddl];
        if (!list) {
            list = new ListFilter(ddl);
        } else if(list.getFilter() == value) {
            return;
        }
        var timerId = COURSE_ID_List_timerId[ddl];
        if (timerId) {
            clearTimeout(timerId);
        }
        COURSE_ID_List_timerId[ddl] = setTimeout(function() { list.SetFilter(value); }, 1500);
        COURSE_ID_List[ddl] = list;
        return;
    }
})();
```

and

```
<input name="Course" type="text" id="COURSE_ID" onkeyup="setFilter('COURSE_ID', this.value);" onblur="setFilter('COURSE_ID', this.value);" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to...

```
function SetFilter(ddl, value) { 
  if (COURSE_ID_List == undefined) 
    COURSE_ID_List = new ListFilter(ddl); 
  clearTimeout(COURSE_ID_List_timerId); 
  COURSE_ID_List_timerId = setTimeout(function() { COURSE_ID_List.SetFilter(value);}, 1500); 
}
```

and

```
onKeyUp="SetFilter('COURSE_ID', this.value);"
```

A more generic approach would use prototyping...

```
var Lists = { COURSE_ID_List: null, ... };

function SetFilter(ddl, value, list) { 
  if (Lists[list] == null) 
    Lists[list] = new ListFilter(ddl); 
  clearTimeout(COURSE_ID_List_timerId); 
  COURSE_ID_List_timerId = setTimeout(function() { Lists[list].SetFilter(value);}, 1500); 
}
```

Comment: There could be more than list e.g. COURSE_ID_List and SUBJECT_ID_List. The way it's working at the moment is that there's a specific SetFilter function for every list just like you've done. I was just hoping there would be a way just to have one generic SetFilter function.

Answer (score 1):

Pass by reference is awkward in JavaScript.  Objects have only their value passed by reference, so re-assigning to a variable name results in that variable name having a new value, but the original variable retains its value.

I was going to post a similar solution to [Yves M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096063/referencing-javascript-variable-in-onkeyup-event-problem/4096102#4096102), but I see from your comments that you already tried that.  The other solution is to use objects and manipulate their properties instead.  Something like the following is what I think you're trying to achieve,

```
function SetFilter(ddl, value) {
  if (Lists[ddl] == undefined)
    Lists[ddl] = new ListFilter(ddl);

  clearTimeout(List_timerIds[ddl]);
  List_timerIds[ddl] = setTimeout(function() { list.SetFilter(value);}, 1500);
}

var Lists = {};
var List_timerIds = {};
```

Also, I'd like to re-iterate my comment about choosing an alternative event for input handling.  *oninput* (HTML5) and *onpropertychange* (Internet Explorer) do a much better job of catching text input.